How to find the range of hyperbola's eccentricity?
$F_{1}$ ,$F_{2}$ are left and right focus points of the hyperbola C: $\frac{x^{2}}{a^{2}} - \frac{y^{2}}{b^{2}} = 1$ respectively. Point O is the origin of the coordinate, M is an arbitrary point on C and above the x-axis. H is a point of $MF_{1}$. Given that $MF_{2}$ is perpendicular $F_{1}F_{2}$ and $MF_{1}$ is perpendicular to OH. $|OH| = \lambda|OF_{2}|$ , where $\lambda$ $\in (\frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{2})$ then the range of eccentricity of hyperbola C is?
The given answer is $(\sqrt2, \sqrt3)$
I began by assuming M and trying to find OH, but can't arrive at the result. Any help would be appreciated!

Welcome to MSE. When writing fractions, the LaTeX \frac{}{} can be quite useful.

For future posts you may be expected to apply math formatting.
https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference
For now, I've suggested an edit.

Okay thanks, will keep that in mind.

HINT. $$OH:OF_1=MF_2:MF_1$$

Really helpful, got the answer now. Thanks
